# Can only access sites using https, what could cause this?

Tags: http, https

Anyone know what could possibly going on here? This has been going on with my home network since yesterday and my ISP has no idea what's going on. Through all my devices (phone, laptop, desktop), I can't connect to any sites unless they use https, then I can access them fine.

Could this possibly be the cause of a virus? I've ran Malwarebytes, and I constantly have it in protection mode and nothing was found, but I can't even update the virus database because it won't connect (though the latest one is from 2 days ago)

Anyone have an idea of what can possibly be going on here?

Comment: To help you we need some details about your network setup and equipment (modem and router, etc). Do these devices work as expected on other networks?

Comment: It's a Comcast router and model combined, my laptop and phone are connected via wi-fi, my desktop through a cable. I know my phone works on other networks.

Comment: I believe this is a Comcast issue (not that they would be able to tell). Try this: Power off and remove the battery from the modem/router for an hour. Replace the battery, plug into power and restart. Allow several minutes for the modem to initialize. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: I'll try that out thanks. And yeah it does sound like a Comcast issue to me, I've gone through all the customer support (basically they just restart the router and asked me to renew my IP). After a while they routed me to some tech support company who claimed it's my proxy settings (apparently my proxy settings are global between browers, devices and different OS's). Sorry I'm rambling, I'll try that out, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Comcast issue. Try this:

1. Power off and remove the battery from the modem/router for an hour.
2. Replace the battery, plug into power and restart.
3. Allow several minutes for the modem to initialize.

This should resolve the issue.